# OpenCV - How to defined a variable of type CvvImage in Opencv 2.3?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, opencv

I'm writing a program to capture image frames from a camera and to dispay them on the MFC  picture control window. My program is using **MFC** in **OpenCV 2.3** and **Visual studio 2010**.

but I am not able to use the function **CvvImage**. 
It says it is undefined.  This function comes under the highgui.h header file.  When I check the header file and compared it with Opencv 1.0 I saw that this function is not defined here.

When I use this program on opencv 1.0 and visual studio 2008 it works fine.  and executes. 
but using visual studio 2010 and opencv 2.3 it is not defined.

**please help use the CvvImage or tell me the equivalent used in opencv 2.3.**

I do no want to use IplImage. because then I am not able to place my image frame on the MFC picture control window.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

WEll after many days thinking i finally got the answer.

What we need to do it to add a class CvvImage.cpp and the header file CvvImage.h to the open cv directory.

and in the main program we need to define #include "CvvImage.h"

Comment: What a weird mess is this?! Please reformat your answer! Or better, condense it to the neccessary parts!